# What will happen when I run the command below?

Tags: bash

What will happen if it is stored in `/etc/hosts`?

```
echo "192.168.1.34  www.soa.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: "What will happen when i run the below command?"

Comment: Who is telling you to run this command? Do you know and trust that person?

Answer (score 4):

If you run it as root, the command will add an entry to the /etc/hosts file. The entry will map the name www.soa.com to the IP address 192.168.1.34, which is probably a host on your local network. The effect of this will be to redirect network traffic that's supposed to go to www.soa.com to some machine nearby.

Comment: You don't actually have to be root -- you just need write permissions to /etc/hosts.  Normally, it is owned by root and only writable by owner, but you can change that.

Comment: that means if I run this on linux , then other pc on the same network will redirect to my machine if they wanna go to www.soa.com.

Comment: No, that won't happen, because /etc/hosts only affects name resolution on the local machine. Your PC doesn't know or care what the /etc/hosts file on your Linux machine says. The PC has its own hosts file (see http://superuser.com/questions/525688/whats-the-windows-equivalent-of-etc-hosts) but not sure if you can just modify it, probably depends on your version of Windows

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt

Comment: If you want to override the IP address of www.soa.com for your whole network, you should see if you can do it on your router. Usually routers advertise themselves as the DNS server for your network, and if yours does, you may be able to change how it resolves names. Note that this kind of lookup is different from the /etc/hosts-based lookup. They both accomplish the same thing (map names to IP addresses) but one uses the local hosts database in /etc/hosts while the other contacts a DNS server. DNS is so ubiquitous now that /etc/hosts is practically vestigial.